# Display Excel Sheet Data without configuring Excel Services in Sharepoint

Tags: excel, excel-services, office-web-apps

We have configured Office web apps in our SharePoint 2013 environment so now we don't want to configure Excel Services in this environment. Office web apps are working fine we are able to perform the task what ever we want.

Now the problem is that we want to display the data of some excel files (Excel files are saved in some library with in same SharePoint) in a web part page (with the help of some web part or any other option) but we don't want to configure excel service as we have already configured OWA and OWA is working as per our requirements.

"I know if we configured Excel services, we can achieve this by using Excel Web Access web part to display excel data but I can not do this."

So please help me, how can we display excel data in our environment with the help of OWA and without configuring Excel Services.

Thanks in Advance,

Abhinav Agarwal